# Regression model for road accidents data

Tags: multiple-regression, multinomial-distribution, probit

I want to model road accidents data to identify 1) the major causes of accidents and 2) predictors that can explain the accident severity measured by the passengers injury level (minor, major, fatal).

I'm not clear if 1) can be approached at all since I'm limited to road accident reports. How can we claim that, say, speed higher than 30mph increases the chances of car accidents (by a certain coefficient amount) when we can't possibly include all the observations where the higher speed *did not* cause an accident?

And for 2) should I apply a multinomial logit or a probit model?

Some resources found [here](http://www.amazon.com/J.N.-Ivan/e/B00J0SHG1O/ref=ntt_athr_dp_pel_3).

Comment: You will not be able state that "speed higher than 30mph increases the chances of car accidents" if you do a regression on severity, but you will be able to state that speeds higher than 30mph increases the severity of the accident (given that there was an accident). If you are only interested in whether there was an accident or not, you will be able to estimate P(speed>30 | accident=True). Your statement is P(accident=True | speed > 30) and to compute it you need Bayes theorem and at least two other estimates of different probabilities.

Comment: You are right that you need more data to even begin to address 1.  State departments of transportation (in the US) routinely monitor how many cars/day use various road segments.  They also sometimes monitor the speed of the cars going by.  These data are often, in principle, publicly available because of freedom of information laws.  So, you may be able to get the data you need to round out your dataset.

Comment: We often hear of high speed as one of the major causes of road accidents. I wonder how do they calculate that.

Comment: In the UK too a lot of Dept for Transport analysis is based on data at the road-segment level, as @Bill explains for the US; looking at how the average & the *variance* of speed, among other factors, can predict the number of accidents. That doesn't necessarily translate easily into a relationship between speed & accident risk at the level of the individual driver - but then the DfT can only act at the road-segment level, changing speed limits, putting in cameras, &c. Nevertheless some studies have looked at it at the driver-level: see e.g. ...

Comment: ... [Taylor (2000), "The effects of drivers' speed on the frequency of road accidents", *TRL* 421](http://www.trl.co.uk/reports-publications/report/?reportid=2580), which used surveys to estimate drivers' typical speeds. Case-control studies are going to be rarer, & experimental data non-existent.

Comment: Robert, I have not read it in a good while, but you might use this paper (& its lit review) to start searching for the answer: http://www.nber.org/papers/w9094

Answer (score 1):

You are right about 1) and it is even worse than that.  You cannot determine if speed causes accidents without intervention, i.e. forcing people to change their speed.  Without intervention, you don't know if there is a common cause to both speed and accidents, i.e. accident-prone people might tend to drive faster.

For 2) either model sounds reasonable, although I recommend a version where the categories are known to be ordered (this is known as [ordinal regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_regression)).

Comment: 1) So how are those road accident research normally conducted? What can I do with accident reports data?

Comment: @RobertKubrick have you ever read the fine print and limitations of those reports?  They go one for pages.  You can't determine it with certainty, but you can find some causal EVIDENCE.